# matplotlib imshow in loop exits with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, imshow

I am having troubles showing images using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` in a loop.
The program randomly stops running with the message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

`plt.pause()` does not help.

- I have noticed that the program also crashes when I try to drag the
  window, in which the image is open.
- Running the code from console gives the same error.

I have already reinstalled python and PyCharm but had no luck fixing the issue.
I use Python 3.7, PyCharm 2020.2.3(Community Edition), Windows 10.

Does anybody know how to deal with it?

Comment: are you possibly running out of memory? can you check if that is the case?

Comment: Hi pygri! I have checked and it doesnt seem to be the case. Still having the same issue

Comment: then I am not sure where to go from there, sorry. I was suspecting that you may not have been properly disposing of the images after displaying them, but if memory is OK it may be something else entirely

Comment: no worries! thanks for helping anyway. I have had this issue for quite some time and could not find a solution so far.